# Zend Framework: Paypal

Tags: zend-framework

I have been attempting to implement a paypal functionality into my application by following the example here: http://www.alexventure.com/2011/04/02/zend-framework-and-paypal-api-part-2-of-2/

This is my paymentAction in my controller.

```
public function paymentAction()
{
    $auth= Zend_Auth::getInstance(); 
    $user= $auth->getIdentity();
    $username   = $user->username;

    $cart = new Application_Model_DbTable_Cart();

    $select = $cart->select()
    ->from(array('c' => 'cart'))
    ->join(array('p' => 'product'), 'p.productid = c.productid')
    ->where('username = ?', $username)
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false);

    $fetch = $cart->fetchAll($select)->toArray();

    $paypal = new My_Paypal_Client;
    $amount = 0.0;

    foreach($fetch as $item) {
        $amount = $amount + ($item['price']*$item['quantity']);
        }

    $returnURL = 'http://www.google.com';
    $cancelURL = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
    $currency_code = 'USD';

    $reply = $paypal->ecSetExpressCheckout(
        $amount, 
        $returnURL, 
        $cancelURL, 
        $currency_code
        );

    if ($reply->isSuccessfull()) 
    {
        $replyData = $paypal->parse($reply->getBody());
        if ($replyData->ACK == 'SUCCESS' || $replyData->ACK == 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING') 
        {
            $token = $replyData->TOKEN;
            $_SESSION['CHECKOUT_AMOUNT'] = $amount;

            header(
            'Location: ' . 
            $paypal->api_expresscheckout_uri . 
            '?&cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . $token
            );
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        throw new Exception('ECSetExpressCheckout: We failed to get a successfull response from PayPal.');
    }

}
```

However, this is the error that returns.

```
Message: No valid URI has been passed to the client
```

Where did i go wrong? I would be happy to provide code from other areas of my application if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Http_Client::request()` has not received a valid instance of `Zend_Uri_Http`.

Here's where the error occurs:

```
    /**
     * Send the HTTP request and return an HTTP response object
     *
     * @param string $method
     * @return Zend_Http_Response
     * @throws Zend_Http_Client_Exception
     */
    public function request($method = null)
    {
        if (! $this->uri instanceof Zend_Uri_Http) {
            /** @see Zend_Http_Client_Exception */
            require_once 'Zend/Http/Client/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Http_Client_Exception('No valid URI has been passed to the client');//Note the exact message.
        }//Truncated
```

The only obvious error I see in the code you provided is :

```
$paypal = new My_Paypal_Client;//no () at end of declaration
```

I hope you implemented part one of the [tutorial](http://www.alexventure.com/2011/02/28/zend-framework-and-the-paypal-api-part-1-of-2/) where the constructor is built. Otherwise you may just need to pass a better uri.

**[EDIT]**
I think your problem is here:

```
//needs a uri value for Zend_Http_Client to construct
$paypal = new My_Paypal_Client($url);
```

`ecSetExpressCheckout` does not construct the http client so it has no idea of where it's requesting the token from.

Alternatively you could just add this line below $paypal and above $reply:

```
//pass the uri required to construct Zend_Http_Client    
$paypal->setUri($url);
```

I just hope you know what the url shouild be.

Good Luck.

Comment: I fixed the new My_Paypal_Client() line already. I have implemented part 1 of the tutorial. I assume the issue is with my return and cancel URL?